# about the declaration of a mixture of array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

May someone kindly explain the rules of declaring a mixture of array and pointer?

Below is what I have found. However, I do not understand why `int *p[10]` means `an allocation of 10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int *)`, while `int (*p)[10]` means `declaring a pointer to an array of 10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int)`. What are the rules behind these codes?

```
int p[10];     //10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int) are allocated and named as p
int *p[10];    //10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int *) are allocated and named as p
int (*p)[10];  //p is a pointer to an array of 10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int)
```

Currently, my guess for the rules is:

`xxx[10]` would be interpreted as `please allocating 10 memory blocks in which each blocks may store xxx`. Therefore, `int *p[10]` would be resulted in `10 memory blocks in which each can store data of type int *`;

`(*p)` would be interpreted first due to `()`, and this would lead to a pointer pointing to somewhere. Therefore, `int (*p)[10]` would be resulted in `a pointer to an array of 10 consecutive memory blocks (each can store data of type int)`.

Sorry for my bad English. Hopefully, you can understand what I mean.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C uses *infix notation* for types.  An array of 10 ints has the type `int [10]`, however anything which is *derived* from the array type, has the derivation go in between the `int` and the `[10]`  (not at the end as in some other languages).

If we declare a variable having this type, it is not `int [10] arr;`, it is `int arr [10];`

Similarly, a pointer to array of 10 ints is not `int [10] *`, but it is `int (*) [10]`.

The reason `()` are required is because `int * [10]` would be an array of 10 `int *` . The `()` have the effect of breaking up the `int` and the `*` , so that it cannot be parsed as the type `int *`. They don't "mean anything" apart from that.

Answer (score 2):

You actaully alread quoted the rules. The only thing to add is that you better write it like this:

```
int* p[10]; 
   ^------ belongs to int

int (*p)[10];
     ^---- belongs to p, ie p is pointer to int[10]
```

If you are unsure you can always check on http://cdecl.org/

PS:
Actually syntaxwise it would make sense to write (1) rather than (2):

```
int *a;  // (1)
int* a;  // (2)
```

because to declare two pointers one has to write:

```
int *a,*b;    // and not  int *a,b; !!
```

However, semanticswise the `*` is part of the type, ie. both (1) and (2) declare an `(int*)` named `a` which is more clearly expressed by (2). For this reason declarations of more than one pointers are usually placed on seperate lines:

```
int* a;
int* b;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a very clear and perfect answer!:)

Comment: Hello. Excuse me. I have tried to write `int* a,a2;`, and checked for their size. However, I found that, the size of a is different with a2. According to the notion that `*` belongs to `int`, should not both of them have the same size? Thank you for your time!:)

Comment: @我永遠最愛伊茲娜 Actually I dont know the correct terms to explain better...Edited the question trying to clarify

Comment: @我永遠最愛伊茲娜 hard to explain that one without going into formal grammar terms ...  a declaration consists of a *type-specifier* and some comma-separated *declarators*,  and the type being declared for each identifier is the combination of the *type-specifier* and the rest of its associated *declarator*.

Comment: @tobi303, Thank you very much!:D

Comment: @M.M, Thank you very much!:D Before reading you comment, I didn't know what keywords can be used to search for more details of the related c, c++ knowledge. However, I now may search for *type-specifier* and *comma-separated declarators* to learn more when I am free!:D Thank you very much!